# Matchmaking and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, sprite-kit, multiplayer

I'm working with a multiplayer game using Swift, SpriteKit and Firebase.

It's the first time I'm using multiplayer and **GameKit** so I don't get the concept of matchmaking. I read Apple Documentation but honestly it's not clear, it tells me what ***real-time-match*** can do and shows a little bit of code in objective-c.

I've spent a long time searching about matchmaking in swift and I have only found [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/CreatingaHostedMatch/CreatingaHostedMatch.html).

I know that every match start with `matchRequest` but I don't know what to do after that.

How does matchmaking work? What methods should I be using? Does anyone know where I can find an example?